# How can I make my QLabel scroll with the written text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

Im making a calculator with pyqt5 but when the calculator QLabel overflow I need it to scroll with the last digit on the QLabel

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a read-only `QLineEdit` instead of a `QLabel`. For example

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        # mimic QLabel by making self.label read-only and removing the frame and background color
        self.label.setReadOnly(True)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color:#00000000; font-size: 20px; border:0px")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setPlaceholderText('type something')

        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.text_edit.textChanged.connect(self.label.setText)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]